# Help with integration of first moment from PBE

Tags: integration, derivatives, matlab, moment-generating-functions, simulink

I'm wondering anyone can help me with the following integration:

$$\frac{d(m_0 V)}{dt} = BV$$
where $B$ is just a constant, $V$ is a variable parameter. Product rule must be applied somehow?

**EDIT**: m_0 is not constant! it is variable also.

I want to implement it in MATLAB/Simulink. It is basically first moment in the Population Balance Equation, no. 8 from this paper [[LINK]](http://silverstripe.fkit.hr/cabeq/assets/Uploads/02-1-18.pdf).

Thanks and Kind Regards.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You have now changed it so that $m_0$ and $V$ are functions of time, can you define $m_0$ otherwise there is no simplification of this ODE

Comment: Yes, Initially I forgot to mention that both of them are functions of time. But, **`V`** is sort of known as follows: **`dv/dt=Q`**; [Q is just a number]. 
As **`m_0`** is needed, this makes it possible...?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Actually, the paper you share describes some methods to implement this (for variable $m_0$, of course): MoM is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $B,m_0$ are constants, then
$$m_0\frac{d V}{dt} = BV$$
or
$$\frac{d V}{V} = \frac{B}{m_0}dt$$
Integrating both sides as
$$\int \frac{d V}{V} =\int  \frac{B}{m_0}dt$$
will give you
$$\ln V =  \frac{B}{m_0}t + K$$
which is equivalent to
$$\exp(\ln V) =\exp(  \frac{B}{m_0}t + K) =\underbrace{ \exp(  K) }_C\exp(  \frac{B}{m_0}t) $$
Finally you get
$$V = C \exp(  \frac{B}{m_0}t) $$

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This is correct in case of m_0 being a constant value. But m_0 is not a constant (I forgot to mention it)

So, it would be like:

V(dm_0/dt) + m0(dV/dt) = BV. 

Which, at the end becomes: 

Int(dm_0) + int(m_0 * dv/v) = B * int(dt)

Comment: but do you know it ? @Soheil

Comment: Apparently, it should not be a constant value because of physics of the problem. It is a dynamic value that changes by time. @Ahmad

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d(m_0V)}{dt}=BV$$
since $m_0$ and $B$ are constants we can say:
$$m_0\frac{dV}{dt}=BV$$
we can now rearrange this to say:
$$\frac 1V\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{B}{m_0}$$
Now just integrate both sides:
$$\int\frac 1V\frac{dV}{dt}dt=\int\frac{B}{m_0}dt\Rightarrow\ln|V|=\frac{B}{m_0}t+C$$
Now exponentiate both sides:
$$V=e^Ce^{\frac{B}{m_0}t}$$
Now notice that when $t=0$,$V=e^C$ so we will let $V_0=e^C$ so:
$$V=V_0e^{\frac{B}{m_0}t}$$